# Count number of specific characters in input string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

Im trying to count the number of letters, numbers and special characters in an input string

The user would type the string and then finish with a * to finish the program should then display a count for the number of letters numbers and special characters

So far i have this but i get errors on line 21 which i think is the else statement

The exact error message i get is "./masher3: line 21: 0: command not found"

```
#!/bin/bash

numcount=0
charcount=0
othercount=0

echo "Input string"

for char in $@
do
        if [[  $char == "*" ]]
        then
                break
        elif [[  $char == '0-9' ]]
        then
                $numcount = $numcount + 1
        elif [[ $char == 'A-Z' ]]
        then
                $charcount = $charcount + 1
        else
                $othercount = $othercount + 1 <----- Error on this line
        fi
done

echo $charcount
```

Comment: please enumerate the lines, and edit the right line of the error, if possible also the error message. Thanks

Comment: Do your really want to use `*` to terminate input?

Comment: You are not reading input from stdin. Your program takes input from arguments.

Comment: You cannot put spaces around `=` in a shell variable assignment (the syntax does not allow it).

Comment: shell arithmetic looks like `numcount=$((numcount + 1))` -- see [3.5.5 Arithmetic Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program is written in pure bash (without calling any external programs).

Also look below the code – I added some more information.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Print the message without going to next line (-n)
echo -n "Your input string: "

# Read text from standard input. ‘-d '*'’ stops
# reading at first ‘*’ character. Remove it to
# terminate on press of key Enter.
# Result is stored in variable $input.
#
# -e enables backspace and other keys.
read -ed '*' input

# Jump to next line
echo

# Fill all counters with zeros
letters=0
digits=0
spaces=0
others=0

# While $input contains some text…
while [[ -n "$input" ]]
do
  # Get the first character
  char="${input:0:1}"
  # Take everything from $input except
  # the first character and store it again
  # in $input
  input="${input:1}"

  # Is the character space?
  if [[ "$char" == " " ]]
  then
    # Increase the $spaces variable by one
    ((spaces++))
  # Else: If the $char after removal of all
  # letters in (english) alphabet is empty string?
  # That will be true when the $char is letter.
  elif [[ -z "${char//[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]/}" ]]
  then
    # Increase $letters
    ((letters++))
  # Else: If the $char …
  # Just the same for digits
  elif [[ -z "${char//[0123456789]/}" ]]
  then
    ((digits++))
  # Else increase the $others variable
  else
    ((others++))
  fi
done

# Show values
echo "Letters:          $letters"
echo "Digits:           $digits"
echo "Spaces:           $spaces"
echo "Other characters: $others"
```

---

Also open/download the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) (available as [single page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html), [plaintext](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.txt), [PDF](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.pdf)). You probably have one copy already installed if you use Linux. Try commands `info bash` (usually shows hypertext browser if installed) or `man bash` (single page documentation but usually the same). It is sometimes hard to understand for beginners but you will learn more information about this programming language.

Bash has many *builtin* commands (such as `read`, `[[`, `echo`, `printf` etc.) that work like ordinary commands. Their help is in the Reference Manual or can be shown by typing `help command_name` in your bash shell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer is there anyway to get it so backspace doesnt count as input

Comment: Wait 5 minutes and I will add comments. Comments inserted.

Comment: And don't forget to click the ✓ button to mark this as the correct answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how do i accomadate for backspace becuase if i backspace i get ^?

Comment: Do you **really** want to end the input with `*`? `Enter` key would be better and without such problems (remove the `-d '*'` part from `read` command).

Comment: To test that a char is a letter, you can write `[[ $char == [[:alpha:]] ]]` -- similarly `[[ $char == [[:digit:]] ]]` -- inside double brackets, the `==` operator is a *pattern matching* operator (see `help [[` and [3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching))

Answer (score 0):

See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59336075/4529168) for solution.

---

Your program is quite weird.

- Assignment into variable looks like `variable=42` (not `$variable = 42`)
- You have to use `$((…))` syntax to perform calculations
- `[[ $char == '0-9' ]]` means “When the character is exactly `0-9`
- `$char` contains separate *arguments* of the program, not characters in input.

---

`$othercount = …` means “run command with name specified in variable `$othercount` with arguments `=` and `…`.

## Assigning into variable in bash

You have to NOT write `$` before variable name when you want to assign to it and you have to have NO whitespace before `=`:

```sh
my_variable=42

variable_2=$(($my_variable + 8))

echo $my_variable # Prints “50”
```

Comment: I dont get an error anymore but it just says its 0 So i do ./program HELLO* and it runs and says Input string and then 0

Comment: @h7989 I'll send you my solution in separate answer. Your program is quite weird.